# Pi value estimation with series

Tags: matlab, increment, series, pi

Here's my problem:

Compute the value of π using the following series:

```
((π^2)-8)/16=[sum from 1 to pos. infinity] 1/(((2n−1)^2)*((2n+1)^2))
```

• Find the smallest number of terms required to obtain an absolute value of the error on π smaller than 10e−8.

Here's my code:

```
x=0;
for i=1:1000

    x=x+(1/((((2*i)-1)^2)*(((2*i)+1)^2)));
    z=sqrt((x*16)+8);
    error=abs(z-pi);
    if (error < 10e-8)
        i
        break
    end
end
```

The answer that I get is 81 when the loop breaks, but it is not the right answer. I have been trying to figure out what is wrong with my code that it doesn't do what I need.

I've been staring at the code for quite a while and cant see where I made a mistake.

Comment: umm.. don't you want to look at z when you break out of the loop? In fact.. I might print out the difference between z and pi.

Comment: >but it is not the right answer
Why not? Everything looks right. Mathematica gives the same result

Comment: I believe it is the right answer too, but am being told that it is not with no clues as to where I am making a mistake.

Comment: When I do this I get `abs(z-pi)=9.7997e-08`, so your code does work. Furthermore, with `i=80` you get an error of ~1.01e-7 which is > 10e-8. What answer were you expecting? The only thing I can think of is you misread and it was (say) 1e-8 instead of 10e-8?

Comment: @Johnny Hieu Le May be this an error not on value of pi, but on ((π^2)-8)/16 ? it will give you 59 terms in this case.

Comment: @Cheery The problem specifically states the error on pi.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee It is 10e-8 not 1e-8.

Comment: It's possible that since they say "using the following series" they mean the error on  ((π^2)-8)/16 as @Cheery says -- I suggest you ask your tutor for clarification as perhaps the question is just worded really ambiguously.

Comment: Found the problem. 10e-8 should have been 10^-8. Somehow copying it over converted it. Thanks everyone for the help!!!

Comment: @JohnnyHieuLe, in case you found the problem, please post it as an answer and accept it yourself. This helps future generations of programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. The error is supposed to be less than 10^-8 not 10e-8. Somehow the numbers got changed over when copying.